# Unable to get 2017 for mac

Tags: download, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to download VS2017 for my mac. But I am unable to get the link through which I can able to download VS2017. I have been getting 2019 but I wanted to install VS2017. Can someone provide me the link to download vs2017 please.

Comment: why you need 2017? use 2019

Comment: @Alexan, The IPad displaying a white screen because of the Xcode 11.3 version. To solve this issue I need the VS version which is compatible with Xcode 11.0. So I am looking for it.